# Python Global Variable based on mouseClick

Tags: python, global-variables

I am trying to define a ROI using OpenCV mouse event call back and the below code does not recognize the global variables defined in the mouseClick function.

```py
import cv2

def mouseClick(event,xPos,yPos,flags,params):
    global pnt1
    global pnt2
    global evt

    pnt1 = (xPos,yPos)
    pnt2 = (xPos,yPos)
    evt = event
    
    

cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)


cv2.namedWindow("My WebCam")
cv2.setMouseCallback("My WebCam",mouseClick)


while True:
    ignore, frame = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow("My WebCam",frame)
    
    print(pnt1,pnt2,evt)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
cam.release()
```

When I run this program, I get an error saying pnt1 is not defined when executing the print statement inside the while loop. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? Thanks for all your help and taking the time to read this question.

```
print(pnt1,pnt2,evt)
NameError: name 'pnt1' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign `pnt1`, `pnt2`, and `evt` outside of the `mouseClick()` function. The mouse callback may not necessarily run before the program reaches the `print()` statement -- if this is the case, then those variables will be undefined.

```py
import cv2

pnt1 = None
pnt2 = None
evt = None

def mouseClick(event,xPos,yPos,flags,params):
    global pnt1
    global pnt2
    global evt

    pnt1 = (xPos,yPos)
    pnt2 = (xPos,yPos)
    evt = event

...
```

(remainder of the code is unchanged, omitted for brevity)

Comment: Thank you. This resolved my issue.